# Can't get rid of local gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew

I am trying to uninstall ruby and start over. I am can't get fastlane to work because of all the ruby errors - can't find installed gems, etc. I don't code in ruby and have not used gems before this.

So how do I really start fresh?

Environment:

- I am on Big Sur
- Installed ruby with brew
- Added packages with gem
- I have a local Gemfile that looked like

```
gem "dotenv"
gem "fastlane"
```

I did this:

```
% gem uninstall -aIx
INFO:  Uninstalled all gems in
```

and

```
gem clean
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean up complete
```

It looks like it should be showing me a folder here. Not sure if that's a clue.

I also blanked my Gemfile and did

```
bundle clean --force
```

Now when I do `gem list` I still have local gems

```
% gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.4.1)
bundler (default: 1.17.2)
CFPropertyList (2.3.6)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
csv (default: 3.0.9)
date (default: 2.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
etc (default: 1.0.1)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.1.0)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.7)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
libxml-ruby (3.1.0)
logger (default: 1.3.0)
matrix (default: 0.1.0)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
nokogiri (1.10.1)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.1.0)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
rdoc (default: 6.1.0)
rexml (default: 3.1.9)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
shell (default: 0.7)
sqlite3 (1.3.13)
stringio (default: 0.0.2)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

I also see gems in all of the folders listed by `gem env`

```
     - /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to completely uninstall ruby, not merely remove some libraries? So have you run `brew uninstall ruby`?

Comment: Yes I have. I still have tons of local gems. As well as gems in the 'gem paths' folders.

Comment: Mac OS ships with a pre-installed version of Ruby – and as far as I know also some pre-installed gems in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0` (see e.g. [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/do-not-use-mac-system-ruby-do-this-instead/)). Could it be that the gems that you see here are the system ones? Generally, it's advisable to use a ruby version manager like [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/), [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or even [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) which then also allows you to have distinct gemsets per ruby version and therefore not interfere with the system ones.

Comment: ty, that makes perfect sense